# Flutter showDialog on top of a widget

Tags: flutter, chat, message, forward, reply

I'm developing a chat application which allows users to reply to others' messages. I want to make it so that when user long pressed a chat bubble, a dialog will appear directly on top of the bubble with the options to either reply or forward. I tried using showDialog, but the dialog always appears in the center. Is there any way to do this with flutter? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the issue ?

Comment: it's not really an issue but I just want to know how to align my dialog directly on top of a particular widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [focused_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu) plugin

[Example](https://retroportalstudio.medium.com/focused-pop-up-menu-in-flutter-15766d0ab414)

or

You can also try [flutter menu](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-better-flutter-menu-b1472d24a)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [show aligned dialog](https://itnext.io/show-aligned-dialogs-in-flutter-324e922ae54f).

Comment: This works, but focused_menu is closer to what I need. But still, thank you so much :D

Comment: Yah good, Happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

Just use [flutter_smart_dialog: ^4.5.3+7](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_dialog)

[image]

or use [aligned_dialog: ^0.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/aligned_dialog/example)

[image]

Comment: This works, but focused_menu is closer to what I needed. But still, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Make custom dialog by giving scaffold a transperant background. pass your custom widget to the body, align it wherever you want

```
            showGeneralDialog(
                              barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                              context: context,
                              barrierDismissible: false,
                              barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
                              transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                              pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
                                return Scaffold(
                       body:CustomWidgetDialog(), 

                                  );
                              },
                            );
```